# How to get dev console commands like "document.getElements" in pupperteer js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, puppeteer, innertext

So I am trying to get the innertext from a class like in the dev console:
`document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText` but I am trying to get it automated in purppeteer. I have been looking for an answer for 2 days, and the answer is probably pretty easy, I just can't seem to find a working easy answer.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the dev console with the `page.evaluate()`. This should work for you:

```
let text = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked exactly as I wanted it too!!